# How to be specific when saying "every full hour"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

Say that the doors will open only at 9 o'clock, 10 o'clock, 11 o'clock, 12 o'clock etc. How do I phrase the following sentence correctly?

> Make sure to be there every **full** hour.

Is the word "full" correct here? I want to emphasize that it is not just every hour (since that could also be 09:30 and 10:30 and 11:30 and 12:30 etc. because they are one hour apart), but specifically every time the hour reaches 00 minutes.

Comment: A full hour generally means “a full 60 minutes,” rather than carrying the sense of “on the hour” or “at the top of each hour.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how we would say it in the United States: **"Make sure to be there every hour, on the hour."**  I guess other parts of the world might say it this way as well. But this would be a 100% clear way to say it in the United States.

Comment: When the railway from London to Brighton (England) was electrified in the 1930s, the fastest (express) journey time was reduced to around 55 minutes. Previously the trains were slow and irregular, and the rail company announced the new express service as operating "Every hour, on the hour, in the hour".